# Dovecot+Postfix+Spamassassin (virtual users) - Auto move junk

Tags: postfix, email-server, dovecot, spamassassin

So I have a mail server that receives junk mail and I need to forward these junk emails towards the virtual users junk folder. I have a dovecot, postfix, and spamassassin all working together, but my problem is I can't seem to figure out a way to forward the junk mail (mail titled *****SPAM*****) towards the virtual users spam/junk folder. If anyone is able to help me here with this issue that would be wonderful. If you need any information/files feel free to message me.

The system is running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (64-bit), with dovecot, postfix, and spamasssassin.

Answer (score 0):

There is many ways to do what you desire, but I'm prefer the next approach.

`spamassassin` is launched as local service available at file socket instead of IP port. That is for performance.
`exim` is compiled with content-scan option and configured to interact with `spamassasin` that rate messages and return the score. If score is higher than threshold (49 points in my case) some special headers will be added to the message:

```
spamd_address           = /tmp/spamd.sock

. . . . .

acl_data:
accept  hosts           =  : +relay_from_hosts
accept  condition       = ${if >{$message_size}{1M}}
warn    spam            = spamd
        condition       = ${if >{$spam_score_int}{49}}
        add_header      = X-Spam-Score: $spam_score_int
        add_header      = X-Spam-Ooops: Detected
        log_message     = SpamAssassin detected mesage
accept
```

I haven't check for spam messages larger than 1 MiB as far as spam is usually way smaller. Then I've deliver the message to the user's mailbox. I do that via transport through dovecot's `deliver`:

```
localdelivery:
        driver          = pipe
        user            = mailnull
        command         = /usr/local/libexec/dovecot/deliver -d $local_part@$domain -f $sender_address
        temp_errors     = 64 : 69 : 70: 71 : 72 : 73 : 74 : 75 : 78
        envelope_to_add
        return_path_add
        delivery_date_add
        log_output
```

`dovecot` have a `pidgeonhole` plugin that implement `sieve` functionality. All messages are proceeded through the global filter that look like that:

```
####
require "fileinto";
if exists "X-Spam-Ooops"
{
   fileinto "Junk";
   stop;
}
else
{
   # Trigger to launch next script in sequence
   keep;
}
####
```

The logic here is straightforward: if delivered message have the `X-Spam-Ooops` header (assigned by `exim` on the `sa` score), it will be delivered into the `INBOX.Junk` subfolder for each particular user. `else` branch with `keep` verb inside is needed for further proceeding the message through the custom user's filter(s) after global filter has been proceeded.

Comment: Okay I understand that information, but my problem is I can't seem to get sieve to successfully connect with dovecot/postfix/spamassassin. I have really no idea as what I should do to fix this.

Comment: You should explain what you have already done and how services are configured.

Comment: If you have dovecot setup correctly, dovecot itself executes the sieve filters. There's no "getting sieve to connect with whatever".

Comment: Pidgeonhole is a dovecot's plugin invoked at delivery time for each message.